# Pandas: Logical Operations with date

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm new to python (2 weeks experience)

*Can not give specific informations. Because data and code are on my computer at work.*

I struggle with date operations in python/pandas and want to use logical operations like:
if date1 > 2019-7-31 then write 1 in var1
vice versa write 0

also I want to compare columns:
if date2 > date1 then write 1 in var2
vice versa write 0

### Table1

```
ID    date1      date2        
1     2019-10-1  2019-7-2
2     2019-7-30  2019-10-10
.
.
40000
```

### Table 2

```
ID     date1       date2        var1   var2
1      2019-10-1   2019-7-2      1       0
2      2019-7-30   2019-10-10    0       1
.
.
40000
```

Experimented with date.time
Many other suggestions worked with variables only but not with columns.

```py
df.loc[df["date2"] > "date1", "date2"] = 1
```

-> It fails because date1 is read as a string

```py
df.loc[df["date1"] > 2019-7-3, "date2"] = 1
df.loc[df["date1"] > date.time[2019-7-3], "date2"] = 1
```

-> Can not figure out the right syntax, so that `2019-7-31` is read as a date and comparable.

Alternatively is there a way in python/pandas to convert a date in to the 1900 date system?
So `2019-7-31 = 43677 = Year1900+Days43677`.
This would solve all problems with date handling. Because you can easily compare numbers.
Of course I would like to reconvert the 43677 in to an actual date.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: You can use pandas datetime functionality, [here is the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) for almost anything you want to do. You can [convert to datetimes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: Like I said I already used date.time and I can not find anything case related in the documentation.
I see many ways to convert dates but not how to actualy work and calculate with them. Especialy if you want to compare columns

Comment: @MartinFlower check out the solution I have provided to convert string to date time, compare columns and create columns conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert date strings to datetime and compare:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-07-05', '2019-08-01'],
                   ['2019-08-18', '2019-09-03'], ['2019-10-02', '2019-05-03']])

df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df[0]) > pd.to_datetime('2019-07-31'), "var1"] = 1
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df[0]) <= pd.to_datetime('2019-07-31'), "var1"] = 0

df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df[1]) > pd.to_datetime(df[0]), "var2"] = 1
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df[1]) <= pd.to_datetime(df[0]), "var2"] = 0


print(df)
#    0           1            var1  var2
# 0  2019-07-05  2019-08-01   0.0   1.0
# 1  2019-08-18  2019-09-03   1.0   1.0
# 2  2019-10-02  2019-05-03   1.0   0.0
```

Much simpler using np.where()

```
df['var1'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime(
    df[0]) > pd.to_datetime('2019-07-31'), 1, 0)
df['var2'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime(df[1]) > pd.to_datetime(df[0]), 1, 0)

print(df)

#    0           1              var1  var2
# 0  2019-07-05  2019-08-01     0     1
# 1  2019-08-18  2019-09-03     1     1
# 2  2019-10-02  2019-05-03     1     0
```

The running sample is also available at [github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/python/dataframe-conditional-column-addition-57296789.py)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I am looking for. And thank you Quang Hoang. Now I see what you where trying to tell me.<br>
One open question remains:<br>
How do I add ```2019-7-31``` in a calculation?<br>
I always could create a new var combined with ```pd.to.datetime()```<br>
Buit is there a better solution to write a date (not a variable) in an expression? Like <br>
```date1 > the-date-in-numbers```<br>
For now I would do:<br>
```pd.to_datime(mydate)
date1 > mydate```

Comment: `df['var1']=np.where(pd.to_datetime(df[0])>pd.to_datetime('2019-07-31'), 1, 0)` and `df['var2']=np.where(pd.to_datetime(df[1]) > pd.to_datetime(df[0]), 1, 0)`. I'll modify the solution accordingly.

Comment: @MartinFlower updated the solution based on your need, take a look.

Comment: @MartinFlower does this solve your problem or you see some issue?

Comment: @MartinFlower glad to know that your problem is solved. Would you please accept the answer?